# Keep item focussed after onmouseout

Tags: c3.js

Here is an example of my code. I know the initial value, so I apply to focus on it. But if I hover over any of the items, then mouseout, the chart resets to no items being focussed. I thought I could apply the focus again with an onmouseout, but it doesn't work because of scope.

```
var selectedItem = "Banana";

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Apple', 33.3],
            ['Banana', 33.3],
            ['Canada', 33.3],
        ],
        type : 'donut',
        selection: {
            enabled: true,
            multiple: false
        },
        onclick: function (d, i) { selectItem(d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { resetItems(); }
    },
    donut: {
        title: "Select an Item",
    }
}).focus(selectedItem);

function selectItem(d, i) {
    selectedItem = d.id;
}

function resetItems() {
    chart.focus(selectedItem)
}
```

Anybody know what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of chained **.focus()** method - it **returns undefined**, so variable chart becomes undefined too.

Just call initial focus at separate statement after chart initialization.

```
chart.focus(selectedItem);
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/f5y4LLdq/).